# Projecting properties from first matching element inside nested array in mongo agregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Doc schema:

```
{,
    "prop1" : "some value",
    "prop2" : "another value",
    "array1" : [
        {
            "field_a" : "value_a",
            "field_b" : "value_b",
            "array2" : [

            ]
        },
        {
            "field_a" : "value_a",
            "filed_b" : "value_b",
            "array2" : [

            ]
        },
        {
            "field_a" : "value_a",
            "field_b" : "value_b",
            "array2" : [
                {
                    "key1" : "value1",
                    "key2" : "value2",
                    "key3" : "value3",
                },
                {
                    "key1" : "value_1",
                    "key2" : "value_2",
                    "key3" : "value4",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "field_a" : "value_a",
            "field_b" : "value_b",
            "array2" : [
                {
                    "key1" : "value1",
                    "key2" : "value2",
                    "key3" : "value3",
                },
                {
                    "key1" : "value_1",
                    "key2" : "value_2",
                    "key3" : "value4",
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
 
}
```

I want to project `key1`, `key2` where `key3` is `value4` but only once.
when i'm trying to project the array.array2 `"log": "$array1.array2"`, it is returning as expected:

```
    "log" : [
        [

        ],
        [

        ],
        [
                {
                    "key1" : "value1",
                    "key2" : "value2",
                    "key3" : "value3",
                },
                {
                    "key1" : "value_1",
                    "key2" : "value_2",
                    "key3" : "value4",
                }
        ],
        [
                {
                    "key1" : "value1",
                    "key2" : "value2",
                    "key3" : "value3",
                },
                {
                    "key1" : "value_1",
                    "key2" : "value_2",
                    "key3" : "value4",
                }
        ]
    ],
```

One some debugging, when i'm trying to project with the below filter query it is printing empty list,

```
      "variable": {
//                  $arrayElemAt: [
//          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$array1.array2",
              as: "response",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$response.key3", "value4"] }
            }
//          },
//          0
//        ]
      },
```

```
"variable" : [

    ],
```

Looks like it is not iterating over all the objects of the `array2` array.

Expected output:

```
key1: value_1,
key2: value_2
```

Please share if someone can figure out why the `variable` is coming as an empty list.

Comment: Are you looking the result as this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8aEzTwvpRQL)?

Comment: Please provide your expected results. There are different interpretations here....

Comment: @nimrodserok sorry for any confusion. Let me clearly write the expected output.

Comment: @YongShun No. added the expected output.

Comment: Another approach that I've tried is two `$unwind` stages for both the array and then a `$match` and a `$limit : 1` to not give duplicate items which is working but looking for a shorter query probably utilizing `addToFields`.

Answer (score 1):

Since its an array inside an array, one option is to use both `$filter` and `$reduce`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {"array1.array2.key3": requestedValue}},
  {$project: {variable: {
        $first: {$filter: {
            input: {$reduce: {
                input: "$array1",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this.array2"]}
            }},
            as: "item",
            cond: {$eq: ["$$item.key3", requestedValue]}
        }}
  }}},
  {$unset: "variable.key3"}
])
```

See how it works on the [mongodb playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LOoVhdTCZA1)

Comment: added the expected output.

Comment: updated the answer according to your requested response